# How can I access my form data for a has_many_through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This gist of the application is that 'Pros' have multiple video series, which are made up of multiple videos.

My issue lies where each Pro may feature in several videos, and each series may feature multiple pros. I have set this up as a 'has many through' relationship, where pros and series may have many 'features' but each feature belongs to a single pro and series (join table).

Therefore I declared my models as such:

```
class Pro < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :features
    has_many :series, through: :features
end

class Series < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :features
    has_many :pros, through: :features
    has_many :videos
end

class Feature < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :pro
    belongs_to :series
end
```

Pros are created as normal in their own form, however when creating a series I want to specify which Pros are featured in the series.

For which I have attempted:

```
def new
    @pro = Pro.new
end

def create
    @pro = Pro.new(pro_params)

    if @pro.save
        redirect_to pros_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Fairly normal stuff so far...

However, within: ~\views\series_form.html.haml.
I attempt to select the pro for the series from a dropdown box...

```
= form_for @series do |f|
%p
    Title:
    = f.text_field :title
= fields_for(@series, @series.pros) do |u|
    %p= collection_select(:pro, :pro_id, @pros.all, :id, :name, prompt: :true)
%p= f.submit "Submit"
link_to "Back", root_path
```

Collection select gives me a dropdown menu to select a pro, I want to use this information to create a 'feature' for that pro in my database, allowing me to link a series and pro together.

> How can I access the data in this form so I can run @series.features.create(pro_id: @pro.id) or equivalent in the create method?

Answer (score 0):

I may be totally wrong, but I think that if you run something like `@series.pros.create(params)` you will have what you need with the join table populated correctly.